# How to fix audio configuration for aplay while using pulseaudio

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I want to record audio with *arecord*. The same on *audacity* works fine.

So after trying to record like [documented](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160721041734/http://quicktoots.linux-audio.com/toots/quick-toot-arecord_and_rtmix-1.html):

`arecord -f dat -d 5 -D plughw:0,0 /tmp/test.wav`

failing with message: `arecord: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory`

I try to simply play audio: `at /dev/random | aplay -f S16_LE`
failes as well with

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

… what am I doing wrong; or is *pulseaudio* the problem somehow that runs as well?

My device list with `arecord -L`:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Front speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

`alsamixer` "lists" (with F6):

```
- default
0 HDA Intel HDMI
1 HDA Intel PCH
```

Comment: arecord is with ALSA, parecord is with pulseaudio give it a try instead

Answer (score 1):

Pulseaudio grabs all available ALSA hardware devices. That means as long as Pulseaudio runs, you can neither record from nor play to `hw:...` and `plughw:...`.

However, the usual configuration for Pulseaudio includes a compatibility layer for ALSA applications. It looks similar to

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

in your `~/.asoundrc` (or system-wide settings).

This means all ALSA applications using `default` will be redirected to Pulseaudio, with the ability to choose devices via `pavucontrol` etc.

So: (1) either use `arecord -D pulse`, `arecord -D default` or similar, or (2) use `parecord` in the first place, or (3) stop Pulseaudio or use `pasuspender`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer finally helped be get my usb mic working alongside the speaker pHat

Answer (score 0):

Typically while pulseaudio is running, you can use the audio devices which pulse is setup to use, as long as it isn't using them at the same time (without dsnoop for recording any way).

You can see available subdevices using arecorder -l rather then arecord -L. Howewver assuming hw:0,0 is the correct recording device, then;
My solution is to first suspend pulse audio like so :
pasuspender -- arecord -f dat -d 5 -D plughw:0,0 /tmp/test.wav

If you confirm that works, then you can alter your ~/.asoundrc to switch default devices. Switching default devices can be tricky on operating systems with pulse audio. If you want a working example of switching default devices for command line and generic ALSA applications, you can put the following in your ~/.asoundrc file (changing your card name to match what you choose) :

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card "PCH"
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card "PCH"
}
```

If you experience problems where pulse takes over as the default card, [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452150/how-to-run-alsa-application-without-killing-pulseaudio/67578875#67578875).